# Selenium Element Locators - nested div class

Tags: xpath, selenium, element

Can anyone help me how to match this element, I want to click Canada from the list of countries. Selenium (IDE/WebDriver) is not finding the element. 
I have tried in Webdriver:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@class='slick-viewport']/*[@class='grid-canvas']/*[@class='ui-widget-content slick-row odd']/*[@class='slick-cell l1 r1 active selected']")).click();
```

Firepath gives this XPath:

```
.//*[@id='assetsTable']/div[5]/div/div[5]/div[2]
```

Neither of these are working. Obviously, I am not doing correctly. The ids are generated dynamically, and nested, so I'm finding it very difficult to work out. Can anyone have a look and tell me the correct way for the locator please?

Many thanks

PS: Looks like I am not allowed to upload image. So, copy pasted the content below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="dj_gecko dj_contentbox">
<head>
<body id="bodyID">
<div id="pageDiv" class="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="main">
<ul id="mainMenu" class="menuTab">
<div id="partialHost" style="height: 345.117px;">
<div id="assetsBreadcrumbDiv">
<div id="assetsGridDiv">
<ul id="assetMenu" class="menuTab">
<div id="assetsTable" class="defaultGrid slickgrid_109601 ui-widget" style="overflow: hidden; outline: 0px none; position: relative; height: 269.117px; width: 1562px;">
<div style="position:fixed;width:0;height:0;top:0;left:0;outline:0;" hidefocus="" tabindex="0"></div>
<div class="slick-header ui-state-default" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
<div class="slick-headerrow ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: none;">
<div class="slick-top-panel-scroller ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: none;">
<div class="slick-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; outline: 0px none; position: relative; height: 242px;">
<div class="grid-canvas" style="width: 1545px; height: 5975px;">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:775px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:800px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:825px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:850px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:875px">
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0 selected">CA</div>
<div class="slick-cell l1 r1 active selected">CANADA</div>
<div class="slick-cell l2 r2 selected">Y</div>
<div class="slick-cell l3 r3 selected"></div>
<div class="slick-cell l4 r4 selected">CA</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:900px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:925px">
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:950px">
```

Answer (score 3):

//div[text()="CANADA"] should work. If you only want that particular element that is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use * , be explicit in XPath queries.

This works:

```
//div[@class='slick-cell l1 r1 active selected']
```

What do you get when you try your XPath query directly in FireBug?

Comment: I have tried this as well:  driver.findElement(By.id("assetsTable")/div[@class='slick-viewport']/div[@class='grid-canvas']/div[@class='ui-widget-content slick-row odd']/div[@class='slick-cell l1 r1 active selected']")).click();    In Firebug (FirePath), I get XPath this: .//*[@id='assetsTable']/div[5]/div/div[7]/div[2]      but this is not unique,.. other countries can give same XPath.

Comment: OK, have you tried putting this into Firebug? Open the page, open firebug, type in: `$x("//div[@class='slick-cell l1 r1 active selected']")` , does it find anything?

Comment: If I type it ($x("//div[@class='slick-cell l1 r1 active selected']")) Firebug console, it says, "There are no child objects".  I have a long list of countries (240).. Canada is just one of them, but I can't find a way to uniquely identify Canada as other countries can give same XPath !

Comment: In which case, a blanket `div[text()='CANADA']` could work. Have you tried that? My original XPath works OK here BTW. Perhaps there is something else at play. Have you tried this in Chrome at all?